# Python code example optimization

Tags: python, scipy

I was looking at the implementation of the Kolmogorov Smirnov test in `scipy.stats`, and saw the following code:

```
D = np.max([Dplus,Dmin])
if mode == 'asymp':
    return D, distributions.kstwobign.sf(D*np.sqrt(N))
if mode == 'approx':
    pval_two = distributions.kstwobign.sf(D*np.sqrt(N))
    if N > 2666 or pval_two > 0.80 - N*0.3/1000.0 :
        return D, distributions.kstwobign.sf(D*np.sqrt(N))
    else:
        return D, distributions.ksone.sf(D,N)*2
```

I thought it would be better to do it as follows:

```
D = np.max([Dplus,Dmin])
pval_two = distributions.kstwobign.sf(D*np.sqrt(N))
if mode == 'asymp':
    return D, pval_two
if mode == 'approx':
    if N > 2666 or pval_two > 0.80 - N*0.3/1000.0 :
        return D, pval_two
    else:
        return D, distributions.ksone.sf(D,N)*2
```

My implementation does save a call to the expensive distribution survival function, and I felt is a little clearer as well...

But I am not a Python expert, and `scipy` is a very well thought out library (or at least it seems like that to me). So can you please explain why the library did it the first way?

Comment: This question *might* be a better fit on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> My implementation does save a call to the expensive distribution survival function, and I felt is a little clearer as well

No it doesn't. `distributions.kstwobign.sf(D*np.sqrt(N))` is called exactly once ever. Look at the three possible branches. It will only execute once in any given branch.

```
if mode == 'asymp':
    return D, distributions.kstwobign.sf(D*np.sqrt(N))
```

**or**

```
if mode == 'approx':
    pval_two = distributions.kstwobign.sf(D*np.sqrt(N))
    if N > 2666 or pval_two > 0.80 - N*0.3/1000.0 :
        return D, distributions.kstwobign.sf(D*np.sqrt(N))
```

**or**

```
if mode == 'approx':
    pval_two = distributions.kstwobign.sf(D*np.sqrt(N))
    # not the previous if case
    else:
        return D, distributions.ksone.sf(D,N)*2
```

Comment: in the second branch, the same call is executed twice if the second if condition is met?